# Do I take a small nap or a light nap?

Tags: word-choice, nouns, adjectives, collocation

I heard a friends say that he's going to take a *small* nap. Is this correct usage? I thought we only take *light* naps.

Comment: short nap is better.

Comment: Also a quick nap.

Comment: Also a cat nap ;-)

Comment: How about a *little* nap? That's done a lot.

Comment: My jacket has a short nap. Although it's worn away in some places.

Comment: Say what you like, after all, a nap is **sleep lightly or briefly, esp. during the day,** all adjectives are superfluous.

Comment: Hmm... How about "a short nap"?

Answer (score 6):

'Small' doesn't make sense here because the adjective referring to the length of time (duration) of a nap. Small is more of a descriptor for the overall size of something rather than length in particular (such as the saying, "it's a small world").

'Short' is better because it is an adjectives used to describe length (of time or of objects). You might say "that was a short drive" or "the dog is playing with a short stick."

'Quick' is also appropriate here because it is used to describe duration (length of time), such as "it was a quick meeting."

A 'light' nap is also correct, but it is not referring to the length of the nap. It is instead is stating that the nap does not involve a deep sleep, and typically that implies a shorter nap.

Edit: saying "light nap" is similar to "light snack". Snacks are smaller than a meal, but adding the modifier 'light' implies it's a smaller snack than usual, possibly with healthier or less filling food. A light nap might be 5 minutes of just closing your eyes and breathing deeply, barely even sleeping, as opposed to a 2-hour nap where you likely reach deep stages of sleep.

Comment: No nap can involve deep sleep. No nap can be otherwise than short and light.

Comment: Perhaps you only take light, short naps, but [napping can involve deep sleep](http://www.psychologytoday.com/blog/sleepless-in-america/201010/the-mystery-deep-sleep), and since a 5 minute nap is shorter than a 2 hour nap, it is still appropriate to modify the word nap with words like short.

Comment: There's the [10 minute super-nap](http://www.forbes.com/sites/daviddisalvo/2012/07/24/why-you-should-take-a-10-minute-nap-every-day/). Also, there's [power naps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_nap), cat naps, 40-winks, etc. All these are different kinds of naps and not merely different ways of saying nap.

Answer (score 0):

I would assume neither would be necessary. Your friend "is going to take a nap" should suffice since by definition a nap is brief sleep during the day.

Comment: But if you were going to prefix an adjective indicating that the nap is shorter than one would expect the average nap to be...